# React Native Build Failing

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hi I am new to react native and was trying to setup the sample project, but while trying to build the app i am getting following error

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
>
> Skipping device 'd18a96d67d94 - 7.1.2' for 'app:debug': Could not find build 
>       of variant which supports density -1 and an ABI in
>       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>       Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
> Failed to install on any devices.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In which device you're installing the debug app ?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate on a real device? try execute adb devices on terminal and see if there is any device listed.

Comment: Yes i am uing a real device. It is Redmi 4, it is showing the device id when i run adb devices in terminal

Answer (score 0):

1. enable developer mode - In your phone, go to Settings, About phone and click on MIUI version 7 times. You’ll see a pop up which says you are a developer now.
2. Go back to Settings, Additional settings, Developer options and enable USB Debugging.
3. Connect your phone to your PC/Mac and on the phone authorize your computer
4. go back to Developer options, scroll down to find Turn on MIUI optimization and disable it. Your phone will be rebooted
5. Try it now :)

=====

1. cek list devices : adb devices
2. kill adb device : adb kill-server deviceId 329cb478 // is my id devices
3. run again : adb devices
4. npm start
5. Open another console / cmd
6. run this inside folder project : react-native run-android --deviceId 329cb478

Answer (score 0):

If you have error something like this :

```
Running C:\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 329cb478 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Installing the app on the device (cd android && adb -s 329cb478 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
adb: error: cannot stat 'app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk': No such file or directory
Command failed: C:\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 329cb478 install app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
```

===

please cek : app-debug.apk location

mylocation default : C:\Users\base\react_cargo\cargomobile\mobile_json2\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk

and you must move : app-debug.apk

C:\Users\base\react_cargo\cargomobile\mobile_json2\android\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk

```
up for one level folder : "debug"

outputs\apk\debug
--
outputs\apk\
```